# Pass an enum as @WebParam?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jaxb, jax-ws

Is it possible to pass an enum as `@WebParam` in a `SOAP` webservice?

```
@XmlEnum
public enum TestEnum {
   TEST;
}

@WebService
public class WebService {
   @WebMethod
   public void test(@WebParam TestEnum test) {
       Sysout(test);
   }
}
```

At least if I do it this way and test with `soapUI` with `<test>test</test>` the printout is always `null`.

Comment: Have you tried uppercase TEST instead?  The default mapping from String to enum classes will use the enum name(), which will be case-sensitive.

Comment: Great! Would you mind adding this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default mapping from String to enum classes will use the enum name(), which will be case-sensitive, so you should use `<test>TEST</test>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I found, for complex enum mappings one could also introduce an xml adapter as follows:

```
public class EnumAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, TestEnum> {

    @Override
    public TestEnum unmarshal(String value) throws Exception {
        return TestEnum.fromValue(value);
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(TestEnum value) throws Exception {
        return value.toString();
    }
}
```

Use with `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(EnumAdapter.class)` on the `@WebMethod` param.